# Bug recording with logcat Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm trying to make a recording of the emulator screen in Android Studio (Arctic Fox 3.1 patch 2) by Logcat and when I finish recording the option to save the recorded video doesn't appear, I've already reviewed all possible directories and I can't find the video, I think that it was recorded and not saved due to some kind of failure.

To work around this problem I tried to record using the emulator's ... option in the "Record and Play" option, the recording is done, I can save it wherever I want, but the video is being cut with these flaws as illustrated below:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/kdutjlA" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/kdutjlA">bug as logcat screen record</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I've already changed the emulator settings to perform tests and there was no difference in relation to recording with Logcat or with this option that leaves the video failing. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: I have similar issue on MacOS even with real device.
After recording video from Logcat I can see a dialog where to store but it freezes as soon as Save is pressed

Comment: Found report here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199436578

Comment: @AnoDest hello, thank you, i will follow up your problem, maybe solve mine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many unsuccessful tests and researches, I decided to uninstall all SDK tools to test and install again, apparently now it's normal, I don't understand what could have happened, I believe there is a problem with the IDE itself.

Comment: omg, helped me too, thanks. that studio is so annoying...